# Add a third parameter to a login request using JWT

Tags: laravel

I'm working on an api in Laravel and want to edit the login procedure a bit.
Users log in with a username and a password but as a third parameter I want to add an app_id.

This is because usernames can be double in the database when the app_id is different. This is my current login code. It's using JWT as a driver.

```
$credentials = request(['username', 'password']);
        if(!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => ['code' => 1],
                'status' => 'error',
            ], 401);
        }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Kind regards,
Kevin Walter

Edit: My entire AuthController

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('jwt.verify', ['except' => ['login', 'refresh']]);
    }

    /**
     * Login to get JWT credentials
     */
    public function login() {
        //TODO: LOCKOUT AFTER X AMOUNT OF TRIES
        if(!$token = auth()->attempt($this->credentials())) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => ['code' => 1],
                'status' => 'error',
            ], 401);
        }

        return $this->me(true, $token);
    }

    public function checkPin() {
        $username = request('username');
        $pincode = request('pincode');
        $user = auth()->user();

        if($user && $user->username && $user->pincode && $username == $user->username && $pincode == $user->pincode) {
            return $this->outputJson(0, 'auth', 'checkPin',[
                "firebase_key" => $this->create_custom_token($user->uid, true),
                "pin_ok" => 1,
            ]);
        } else {
            return $this->outputJson(0, 'auth', 'checkPin', ["pin_ok" => 0]);
        }
    }

    public function me($withToken = false, $token = "") {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $output = $user;
        $output->groups = $user->groups;
        $output->categories = $user->categories;
        $output->hasPin = $user->hasPin();
        $headers = array();
        if($withToken) {
            $headers["X-TOKEN-RETURN"] = $token;
        }
        return $this->outputJson('0', 'auth', 'me', $output, $headers);
    }

    public function logout() {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using the `LoginController`?

Comment: No I'm not. Custom AuthController. It just extends on Controller

Comment: can you post code in that controller

Comment: Okay I've posted it!

Answer (score 0):

It was just as simple as merging the app_id in the credentials. This is the working example!

```
//Add app ID into the mix of credentials
    protected function credentials()
    {
        return array_merge(request(['username', 'password']), ['app_id' => \request()->header('X-APP-ID')]);
    }

    /**
     * Login to get JWT credentials
     */
    public function login() {
        //TODO: LOCKOUT AFTER X AMOUNT OF TRIES
        if(!$token = auth()->attempt($this->credentials())) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => ['code' => 1],
                'status' => 'error',
            ], 401);
        }

        return $this->me(true, $token);
    }
```